# Updated gradle to new version of libgdx but how to update everything in eclipse?

Tags: java, libgdx

Updated new version libgdx with gradle but no updated libraries in eclipse, easy way to fix this? I tried manually assigning the new libraries but I am using so many the libgdx setup usually does this all for me it is practically easier to delete my project and create a new one and drag the classes in there has to be a better way?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: @centenond apparently it depends on what version of eclipse with the newest version of Eclipse gradle gives me even more problems than before.

Comment: Im using eclipse luna